# ASP.NET MVC: Ignore field(s) when editing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

As I'm in the progress of learning ASP.NET MVC, I ran into a question and into some trouble

I'm trying to create a simple blog, just to test out what I have learned so far. But when it comes to editing and leaving a field i run into a problem.

I'm trying to edit an already submitted post on my blog, the post contains few fields: Id, Headline, Message, Author and Date for the submission which should not be edited, just left as it is.

Here is some code:

My post model:

```
namespace MyBlock.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Author { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Headline { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Message { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My edit:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    Post post = db.Posts.Find(id);

    if (post != null) {
        return View(post);          
    }

    return HttpNotFound();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Post post)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        db.Entry(post).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View(post);
}
```

And my view for edit:

```
@model MyBlock.Models.Post

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Rediger "@Model.Headline"</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Author)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Author)

    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Headline)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Headline)

    @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Message)
    @Html.TextAreaFor(u => u.Message)

    <input type="submit" value="Gem" />
}
```

I know I could throw in a `@HiddenFor(u => u.Date)` and the same date would be submitted. But I bet there is another way than having it as a hidden field in the source code? I mean this isn't that secure in another example? So I want something else than hidden field here. Can you guys help me out?

If I try to run this as it is. I'm getting an error which is my Date isn't set, which is logic because it want to update that one aswell. But I dont want it to. I want to leave it optional if you could say that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Don't take candy from strangers

In other words, don't take the information from the client and directly update the DB. You should enforce your business rules on the server side and not trust the client to do it for you.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Post post)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var dbPost = db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == post.Id);
        if (dbPost == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        dbPost.Author = post.Author;
        dbPost.Message = post.Message;
        dbPost.Headline = post.Headline;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View(post);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(Post post)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var dbPost = db.Create<Post>();
        dbPost.Author = post.Author;
        dbPost.Message = post.Message;
        dbPost.Headline = post.Headline;
        dbPost.Date = DateTime.Now(); // Don't trust client to send current date
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    return View(post);
}
```

In my own project I enforce rules like this at the domain layer by adding custom validation rules to the `ValidateEntity` method.

Comment: Is this the same for submitting, I mean creating/writing data to the db?

Comment: This is working good. I do have a question to the 'writing to the database' How am I to do this? How can I retrive what the user writes in the view? If I should not take that candy :)

right now I have this in my Write ActionResult:

`if (ModelState.IsValid) {
    post.Date = DateTime.Now;

    db.Posts.Add(post);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
   }`

Comment: @KasperHyldalPedersen it's all there for you. The `db.Posts.FirstOrDefault(...)` line queries the database to find the current state of the post, then verifies that the post actually exists. The next few lines prepare to update the post, taking the user input from the action parameter. Finally, `db.SaveChanges()` commits those changes to the database.

Comment: @KasperHyldalPedersen - you shouldn't be adding a post in an edit action.  You only call Add in a create action.  You retrieve what the user wrote exactly like p.s.w.g shows.  You also do not want to set the date.  His point about not taking candy means don't accept values you don't want changed.  Validate and exclude them.  You have to take the values they enter for the Message and Headline.  Also, you probably don't want to update the Author either, although maybe you do want to allow that to be changed.

Comment: Yes yes for editing. p.s.w.g wrote I shouldn't take candy from strangers.. I asked if it was the same for adding/creating posts.

Comment: @KasperHyldalPedersen It's a good rule to live by whenever you're dealing with any client-server architecture. I updated my answer with an example of an appropriate `Add` method.

Comment: Great, most tutorial I have follow simply haven't taken these steps. I guess why? It seems better and more controllable. :)

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Is this still necessary with AntiForgeryTokens?  Or is it still necessary to protect us from valid users who might submit dangerous data?

Comment: @SimonTewsi Yes. Anti-forgery tokens simply protect against CSRF attacks. They help ensure that the request is coming from a valid browser session; they do not validate the content of the request or ensure that the data will not damage or corrupt your database. Of course it depends on your particular application, but in general, I've found that the maxim "*don't take candy from strangers*" is an excellent rule to live by, especially in web or SOA development.

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Thanks for the clarification.  "Don't take candy from strangers" is definitely catchy and easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime is a value type, and cannot be null.  Thus, it can never be optional.

You need to make a it a nullable type.  ie.

```
public DateTime? Date {get;set;}
```

In general, most value types in a ViewModel should be nullable, then you use Required attributes to enforce that they contain a value.  This allows you to tell whether they failed to enter a value, or whether it's a default value.

In your controller, you can then check if the Date has a value with `Date.HasValue` and if so, then save the date.

In regards to security, in this case it's not raelly an issue.  Assuming someone has access to the page (they pass authorization) and they have the right to update the date, then it doesn't matter if the user can bypass it.  All they can do is submit a valid date format.  Unless you want to add logic to ensure that the date is within a specific time period, then you don't have to worry.  The ModelBinder will not bind to a non-valid date format.

If you want to control whether the user can update the date, say based on role, then you could add logic to your controller to check if the date has a value and the user is in the correct role, otherwise issue an error.

**UPDATE:**

I think the easiest solution here is to do two things.  The first is to make Date nullable, as I mention above.  Although this is not strictly necessary if you do not have a form field for Date in your view, if you were to add a form field later then you would get a validation error if you left the textbox empty.  I like to prevent future errors from occurring if possible.  Also, should someone be posting values to your Edit action manually, and they include a blank Date field, it will fail to validate, rather than simply ignore it.  Making the value nullable allows the value to be completely ignored regardless of its value.

Second, is do what @p.s.w.g suggests, and only update the fields that you want updated.  Retrieve the post from the database, then update all fields except Id and Date.  Then call `SaveChanges()`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - Huh?  His problem is that he wants the date to be optional, this is relevant to the question.

Comment: @MystereMan yes I suppose that would solve fix the error, but the way I read the question, OP doesn't want the `Date` field to be updated in the db when the user edits a `Post`. With your method, if the `Date` field wasn't provided in the form, it would be updated to `null`.

Comment: I'm sorry if I have not been clear enough. But I want my Date field to be optional whether or not it can be updated/edited.. As it is now in my code, I dont want to update that field, as I want it to be as it was since the post in my blog was created

Comment: @KasperHyldalPedersen - You keep contradicting yourself.  You say you want it to be optional, then you say you don't want it to be updated.  Those are two contradictory statements.

Comment: @MystereMan I'm sorry, but I still don't like this solution, because you must still trust the client *not* to send a date when you don't want the date updated.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - it's unclear to me whether or not that's the case.  He keeps saying he wants the date updating to be optional, then contradicts himself.  His primary problem at this point is, however, that Date is ending up required because he's using a value type.  It has to be nullable to solve that problem.  The security problem depends on what he really wants.

Comment: @MystereMan yes, I suppose so. Both our solutions would work, but which one OP should go with depends on the precise requirements.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - no, your solution doesn't work, because it will always fail to validate.

Comment: @MystereMan how so? (I did fix a bug in the code for finding the existing post)

Comment: @p.s.w.g - because Date is a value type, and the model binder makes all value types required, exactly as if there were a required attribute on the field.  Don't believe me? Try it.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - although, come to think of it.. If there is no field in the form, then it will validate, but it will contain the DateTime default value (`DateTime.MinValue`).  If there is a field in the form, but it's empty, then it will fail to validate.

Comment: @MystereMan I wasn't 100% sure, so I launched a new project to test it out - you are correct. It seems you can even do `[Bind(Ignore=...)]` as someone else mentioned to handle empty strings, too.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2cents here. I know this is a simple situation and the answer given is nice and straightforward. But as that list of attributes grows then it could get difficult.

So a different approuch would be along these lines

```
    var t = _db.Blog.Where(x => x.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();

    var info = typeof(Blog).GetProperties();
//properties you don't want to update
    var properties = info.Where(x => x.Name != "xxx" && x.Name != "xxxx").ToList();
  foreach(var p in properties)
   {
      p.SetValue(t, p.GetValue(temp.Volunteer));
   }


   _db.Entry(t).State = EntityState.Modified;
   _db.SaveChanges();
```

But if you are just doing a few fields then the above makes sense. 
Just use your noggin!